# How to change Dropdown menu from Hover to 'Click'

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a navbar menu, and in it there are 3 dropdown menus which default is hover. because the 3 menus are close together, the hover from the dropdown causes a bug/collision, I want to replace it with a 'click' dropdown, where do I have to change the css or javascript code?

```
 <nav class="nav-menu d-none d-lg-block">
    <ul>
      <li class="active"><a href="{{route('welcome')}}">Home</a></li>
      <li class="drop-down"><a href="#">Profile</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#about">WBK & WBBM</a></li>
            <li><a href={{route('sambutan')}}>Sambutan</a></li>
            <li><a href={{route('visimisi')}}>Visi Misi</a></li>
            <li><a href={{route('strukturorganisasi')}}>Struktur Organisasi</a></li>
            <li><a href={{route('pejabat')}}>Pejabat Struktural</a></li>
            <li><a href={{route('sejarah')}}>Sejarah Kejari Sragen</a></li>
            <li><a href={{route('doktrin')}}>Tri Krama Adhyaksa</a></li>
          </ul>
      </li>

      <li class="drop-down"><a href="#">Bidang</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#bidang">Bidang</a></li>
          <li><a href={{route('pembinaan')}}>Pembinaan</a></li>
          <li><a href={{route('intelijen')}}>Intelijen</a></li>
          <li><a href={{route('pidum')}}>Tindak Pidana Umum</a></li>
          <li><a href={{route('pidsus')}}>Tindak Pidana Khusus</a></li>
          <li><a href={{route('datun')}}>Perdata & Tata Usaha Negara</a></li>
          <li><a href={{route('barbuk')}}>Pengolahan Barang Bukti & Barang Rampasan</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav><!-- .nav-menu -->
```

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you posted the CSS/JS as well.  I've styled your HTML to be a very basic nav, but in the future please follow [Stack Overflows Minimal Reproducible guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

> #### Your code examples should be…
>
> - …Minimal – Use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem
> - …Complete – Provide all parts someone else needs to reproduce your problem in the question itself
> - …Reproducible – Test the code you're about to provide to make sure it reproduces the problem

#### That said!

Here's a working example of what you've described, please let me know if this doesn't fit with what you need.

```js
let navLinks = document.querySelectorAll("nav > ul > li");
navLinks.forEach(link => {
  link.addEventListener('click', () => toggleClassName(link, navLinks) );
});

function toggleClassName(link, navLinks) {
  if (link.classList.contains('active')) {
    link.classList.remove('active');
  } else {
    navLinks.forEach(currentLink =>     {currentLink.classList.remove('active');})
    link.classList.add('active');
  }
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;700&display=swap');

* {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

ul {
  list-style:none;
  padding: 1em;
  margin:0;
}

li {
  padding: .5em;
}

nav > ul {
  display:flex;
  list-style:none;
}

nav > ul > li {
  position:relative;
}

nav > ul > li > a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #EF798A;
  padding: .5em;
  border-radius: .3em;
  color:white;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}

nav > ul > li > ul {
  position:absolute;
  top:calc(100% + .5em);
  width: 10em;
  background: #E5C3D1;
  border-radius: .3em;
  max-height:1px;
  opacity:0;
  visibility:hidden;
}

nav > ul > li.active > ul {
  max-height:100vh;
  opacity:1;
  visibility:visible;
}


nav > ul > li > ul > li {
  padding-top: 0;
}

nav > ul > li > ul > li::after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 99%; /* At the bottom of the tooltip */
  left: 7%;
  margin-left: -.5em;
  border-width: .5em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent #E5C3D1 transparent;
}
```

```html
 <nav class="nav-menu d-none d-lg-block">
    <ul>
      <li class="active"><a href="{{route('welcome')}}">Home</a></li>
      <li class="drop-down active"><a href="#">Profile</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#about">WBK & WBBM</a></li>
            <li><a href={{route('sambutan')}}>Sambutan</a></li>
            <li><a href={{route('visimisi')}}>Visi Misi</a></li>
            <li><a href={{route('strukturorganisasi')}}>Struktur Organisasi</a></li>
            <li><a href={{route('pejabat')}}>Pejabat Struktural</a></li>
            <li><a href={{route('sejarah')}}>Sejarah Kejari Sragen</a></li>
            <li><a href={{route('doktrin')}}>Tri Krama Adhyaksa</a></li>
          </ul>
      </li>

      <li class="drop-down"><a href="#">Bidang</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#bidang">Bidang</a></li>
          <li><a href={{route('pembinaan')}}>Pembinaan</a></li>
          <li><a href={{route('intelijen')}}>Intelijen</a></li>
          <li><a href={{route('pidum')}}>Tindak Pidana Umum</a></li>
          <li><a href={{route('pidsus')}}>Tindak Pidana Khusus</a></li>
          <li><a href={{route('datun')}}>Perdata & Tata Usaha Negara</a></li>
          <li><a href={{route('barbuk')}}>Pengolahan Barang Bukti & Barang Rampasan</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav><!-- .nav-menu -->
```